# Attribute data_nonce, data_action, data_postid not allowed errors

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

I am checking code on w3c validator and I keep getting these errors for each individual blog and portfolio post that has the "Like" button attached to it.  Is there something I can do to correct these errors so they validate properly?

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<a href="#" class="like " title="Like this" data_action="likepost" data_postid="74" data_nonce="13e20f93ee">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
    <span class="likecount">2</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have doctype declaration like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and replace the custom attributes as :

```
data-action data-postid and so on.
```

Note the `hyphen` instead of `underscore`. HTML5 allows custom attributes and suggests to use those which starts with `data-` .

```
A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string data-, has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters
```

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)

Comment: I had the doctype but changing the _ to a - on all attributes fixed all of my errors.  Thank you!